# jQuery: trigger event on tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, keypress, keydown

I would like to call a function when the tab key is pressed within any field with the `name="notes"`.

I tried the following but this doesn't fire (using IE 9). What do I have to change here to make this work at least in IE 8 and IE 9 ?

```
$('input[name=notes]').keypress(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 9) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the block of code you've posted. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it is the browser. It works fine in Firefox but not in IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: myFunction is just a small JS function that I want to call with this. That's not the issue as it doesn't fire at all, not even alerting anything in IE.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem I think is in the type of event you're trying to listen to.
The `keypress` event is triggered when a char gets written into an input text, while `tab` key doesn't insert any character. It just blurs the input. Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress).

You might be looking for the `keydown` event instead.

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKr6U/2/). Would it help to get you started?

**JS**

```
$('input[name=notes]').keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (code === 9) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
        alert('it works!');
    }
});
```